# Selenium, Scrolling through a dynamic div that change while scrolling

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to make an Instagram bot that gets all followers of a certain account, now I need to scroll to the bottom of the followers box to load all the followers but the box has no unique element at the end, I tried to scroll down using the down key but it says the element is interactable.

```
def get_followers():
    # click on the followers link
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/a').click()
    time.sleep(1)
    # the followers box
    scroll_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/ul/div')
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.move_to_element(scroll_box).click().perform()
    # scrolling to the end to load all element
    while True:
        scroll_box.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)


get_followers()
```

Is there a more sufficient way to scroll through an element.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[class="isgrP"]').scrollBy(0,350)
```

find the scroll bar element and scroll that using scrollBy

```
scrollbar = driver.find_element_by_class_name("isgrP")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollBy(0,350)", scrollbar)
```

or

This will scroll till the end

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollBy(0,arguments[0].scrollHeight)", scrollbar)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot man, totaly work, can you suggest some resources to learn those js commands.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollBy